# Creating ordered list of verbatims

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, verbatim

I am trying to create an article with code examples and I am currently using `\verbatim` to display the code examples.

Now what I am trying to do is create an ordered list of verbatim at the start like what is displayed with `\tableofcontents` or `\listoffigures`

Is there a way to do this or is there some special `\` command for code examples where it can be done?

This is a given example of what I am doing with verbatim, verbatim

```
\begin{verbatim}

public class classFoo()
{
_strUserName
}
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a working and compilable document. It should be possible to hook into the `verbatim` (environment?) before it goes 'verbatim'. Please note that `listings` is meant for code display, amongst other packages

Comment: Do each of your `verbatim` environment have a caption/title or number associated with them? That's typically the case that one transfers such information to a ToC.

Comment: Your `verbatim` environment neither has a number nor a title. How should this be ordered?

Comment: Thats the thing, I have no idea, I am very new to latex and am unsure how to give numbers nor titles.

Comment: @CasperOrillian: Are you sticking to `verbatim`? Do you have done a lot of writing with `verbatim` already?

Comment: Not yet, the given example is all I have right now, I am happy to change if needs be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`verbatim` is not a numbered or titled environment and there are better ways to display programming code in `LaTeX`, e.g. the `listings` package or `minted`, `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` for fancier setups.

Here is a basic usage of `listings`, defining a specialized `csharp` environment and adding an mandatory title for the environment, which goes as entry to the `\lstlistoflistings` too)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{csharp}[2][]{%
  \lstset{language=[sharp]C,#1,caption=#2}%
}{}




\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings

\begin{csharp}{An easy example}
public class classFoo()
{
_strUserName
}
\end{csharp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, the code is C#, but thank you for that example I can get it working with java

Comment: @CasperOrillian: Well, that's secondary, the language definitions for `C#` are available too.

Comment: I will have to take your word for it, I am having a hard time finding some kind of official documentation, or an explanation that uses \lstnewenviornment. Sorry there probably is some kind of documentation location I just am not aware of it

Comment: @CasperOrillian: See http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf

Comment: Yes! thank you. That does what I was looking for. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @CasperOrillian: You're welcome. There are also `minted` or `tcolorbox` which provide nicer output of the code, if you prefer that